# "Access Denied" logging into Linux Debian via Putty after attempting to change server's time

Tags: linux, debian, login, putty

I was previously able to log into this Linux server just fine.

However, yesterday, after logging in, I manually changed the time (via the date --set [desired time] command), and then changed it back to the current time.

I wanted to see this manual time change in the logs, so I looked at /var/log/ntplog, but it was completely blank.

In the file "/etc/ntp.conf" it said to use a line of code to start doing the NTP logging, so I uncommented out that line of code and saved the file.

Then I repeated the process of manually changing the time.  However, /var/log/ntplog was still completely blank.

Anyway, at that point, someone pulled me away from my desk and my Putty connection timed out.

Now I can't log into the Linux server.  Getting "Access Denied" after I type in my password.  The only other person with an account for logging to this server is getting the same message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, just FYI, it turns out that if the server's time is offset too far from the actual time, it won't let you log in.  Restarting the server caused the time to resync and everything worked fine again.

See here: https://barryp.org/blog/entries/winbind-failure/

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your time on your client is off by several minutes from the server time, authentication will fail. I'm more familiar with Kerberos than the authentication used in SSH, but this will happen in a Windows domain if the PDC is not set to a valid time source (external NTP server). I see this happen a lot and usually have to run the command to make it point to a source instead of itself.

It is also possible, if you manually set the time too far from the actual NTP time, it will not autoupdate.